# WithColumn and nulls, Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I trying to create a new column and compare it with another one, if are equal I have to put "Yes" else "No" as you can see here:

```
+----+-------+-----------+----------+
|Game| statB | statPrev  |  Change  |
+----+-------+-----------+----------+
|  CA|   2   |     2     |   No     |
|  BL|   5   |     2     |   Yes    |
|  CD|  null |    null   |   No     |
|  NT|   4   |     5     |   Yes    |
|  FT|   6   |    null   |   Yes    |
+----+-------+-----------+----------+
```

What I am trying is:

```
var df1 = df.withColumn("Change",
    when($"statB" =!= $"statPrev" 
    || $"statPrev".isNull && $"statB".isNotNull 
    || $"statPrev".isNotNull && $"statB".isNotNull, "Yes").otherwise("No"))
```

But for example when StatB and statPrev are both nulls, I get an "Yes"... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If stateB and statePrev equals :

```
 df.withColumn("Change", when($"stateB" === $"statePrev", lit("YES")).otherwise("NO")).show(false);
```

**output**

```
+----+------+---------+---+
|Game|stateB|statePrev|Change|
+----+------+---------+---+
|CA  |2     |2        |YES|
|BL  |5     |2        |NO |
|CD  |null  |null     |YES|
|NT  |4     |5        |NO |
|FT  |6     |null     |NO |
+----+------+---------+---+
```

if you want to tell No if the null values on stateB and statePrev -

```
df.withColumn("Change",
    when(($"stateB" === $"statePrev") && ($"stateB".notEqual( "null")
      && $"statePrev".notEqual( "null")),
    lit("YES")).otherwise("NO")).show(false)
```

**output**

```
+----+------+---------+------+
|Game|stateB|statePrev|Change|
+----+------+---------+------+
|CA  |2     |2        |YES   |
|BL  |5     |2        |NO    |
|CD  |null  |null     |NO    |
|NT  |4     |5        |NO    |
|FT  |6     |null     |NO    |
+----+------+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, **if are equal I have to put "Yes" else "No"**

It should be

```
var df1 = df.withColumn("Change1",
  when($"statB" === $"statPrev" || ($"statB".isNull && $"statPrev".isNull),
    "Yes").otherwise("No"))

df1.show(false)
```

**Or you could use null safe equal operator as**

```
df.withColumn("Change1",
  when(($"statB" <=> $"statPrev" ), "Yes").otherwise("No"))
  .show(false)
```

Result:

```
+----+-----+--------+------+
|Game|statB|statPrev|Change|
+----+-----+--------+------+
|CA  |2    |2       |Yes   |
|BL  |5    |2       |No    |
|CD  |null |null    |Yes   |
|NT  |4    |5       |No    |
|FT  |6    |null    |No    |
+----+-----+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare equality with nulls, you can use `eqNullSafe` for a simpler syntax:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "Change", 
    when($"statB".eqNullSafe($"statPrev"), "Yes").otherwise("No")
)

df2.show
+----+-----+--------+------+
|Game|statB|statPrev|Change|
+----+-----+--------+------+
|  CA|    2|       2|   Yes|
|  BL|    5|       2|    No|
|  CD| null|    null|   Yes|
|  NT|    4|       5|    No|
|  FT|    6|    null|    No|
+----+-----+--------+------+
```

Comment: Hi mck! you have put it backwards ^^

Comment: Didn't you say "if are equal I have to put "Yes""?