# Pyspark new column when otherwise results in "should be a column" error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a DataFrame in PySpark, and I would like to add a new column based on the value in another column. I know this is fairly common, and I've searched and tried a bunch of different ways, but always end up with the error message `TypeError: condition should be a Column`.

So what I want to do is basically, if the value in one column is not null, then I will do a regex on that column, otherwise I'll do a regex on another column.

My original query looked like this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("new_column", F.when(F.col("column_a").isNotNull,
    F.regexp_extract('column_a', 'myregex', 1))
    .otherwise(F.regexp_extract('column_b', 'myotherregex', 1)))
```

That resulted in the mentioned error. As I was simplifying to figure out where the error was, I could never manage to get it working. So even this simplified example fails with the same error:

```py
df.withColumn("new_column", F.when(F.col("column_a").isNotNull, F.lit("A"))
    .otherwise(F.lit("B")))
```

I've also tried to refer to `column_a` in the following way, without success: `df["column_a"]`

When I search and find examples of people doing the same thing it looks to my untrained eye like it should work. What am I missing?

Comment: `isNotNull()` -- you missed the brackets.

Comment: @samkart That worked, thanks! If you provide a real answer I'll accept it. I guess I must've found the Scala syntax with dollar and `isNotNull` where it seems like the parantheses are not there, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67157518/withcolumn-and-nulls-scala-spark